# How do I specify which sprite to detach , when multiple of the same spritre are added?

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite

I have this method I wrote, to display an empty rock on top of an ore sprite, once resources have been mined from it, and after a certain time, should disappear, so the ore can be mined again, like runescape.

It shows the empty ore after mining, but the problem is, out of the five ores, only one empty ore sprite will disappear, the rest always stay. I think its because when this is called, it doesn't know which "emptyOre" sprite is which. Is there a way to make them unique, or is there a different way to do this?

```
public static void emptyOre(final float oreX, final float oreY, float displayTime){

    emptyOre = new Sprite(oreX, oreY,
            AssetLoaderUtil.emptyOreTextureRegion,
            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    SceneManager.mWorldScene.attachChild(emptyOre);
    //SceneManager.mWorldScene.registerTouchArea(emptyOre);
    emptyOre.setVisible(true);
    emptyOre.setZIndex(2);


    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;

    float mEffectSpawnDelay = displayTime;

    SceneManager.mWorldScene.registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(
            mEffectSpawnDelay, new ITimerCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(
                        final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                    mContext.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            SceneManager.mWorldScene
                                    .detachChild(emptyOre);
                        }

                    });

                    //SceneManager.mWorldScene.detachChild(emptyOre);

                    //emptyOre.setVisible(false);


                }
            }));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want this to sound harsh, but your problem is that you don't understand basic Java programming. You have defined `emptyOre` field as `static`. Even though you forgot to include this in the pasted code, I can tell from the fact, that your method is `static` as well.

What it means is that this field exists in one copy only for the whole class and each of it's instances (but you probably have just one instance). The way you are creating the object, only the last `emptyOre` will be saved.

If you don't need access `emptyOre` from anywhere else, you should define it in the scope of the method:

```
final Sprite emptyOre = new Sprite(oreX, oreY,
        AssetLoaderUtil.emptyOreTextureRegion,
        mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Note that you have to make it `final` because you want to use it in an anonymous class (the handler). What it means that this instance is final is that nbody can change the reference to another instance. That way the anonymous class will remember which `emtpyOre` to work with and when the method is called again, another `emptyOre` is created.

However you won't be able to access this instance from outside of this method. Typically you will want to save instance to a list or a map. Depends on how you want to access them.